# Salesforce: Validation rule to prevent the lookup field in master record related list

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement, where I need to hide the Case number in work performed screen or put some validation so that user cannot change the case number. For the edit work performed, I am able to apply said validation.

How can I hide or put some validation in work performed screen for saving?
I am attaching two screenshots so that you can have a clear picture.

[image: Case screen]

Comment: There arew no screens to see :(

Comment: Did you try change the **Field Accessibility** to read-only in custom field relationship definition?

Comment: mast0r, sorry for that, actually I need  10 point to add an image.

Comment: Martin, case number in work performed screen is a lookup field.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a standard layout page, i would create an extra layout for the certain profile, and then set the field properties to read-only in this layout. So the user can not edit this field anymore.

Comment: I Have already set the field properties read only in the layout.even Work Performed is not adding to case. Case Number is look up field here.

Comment: And you still can edit the field? (i hope you have tested it not like a system admin)

Comment: I have tested it as a normal user and system admin as well. While creating the new work performed as a normal user, under case number it is not showing case id and I was not able to save the work performed for that case.